# Binding data to multiple dropdowns using entity framework in one database connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Lets say we have a stored procedure with 10 `select` statements to bind data to 10 drop downs in a form:

```
CREATE PROC GetMasterData
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT ID,Value FROM Table1
  SELECT ID,Value FROM Table2
  SELECT ID,Value FROM Table3
  SELECT ID,Value FROM Table4.../* other select statements */      

END
```

To write the same `SQL` statements using `LINQ` using `EntityFramework`, the database will be connected 10 times like:

```
var t1Data = from t1 in context.Table1 select t1;
var t2Data = from t2 in context.Table2 select t2;
var t3Data = from t3 in context.Table3 select t3;
var t4Data = from t4 in context.Table4 select t4;
etc....
```

Can we combine the above `LINQ` statements or just execute the `LINQ` statements in a way that we get all the data in one connection?

**EDIT:**

I am aware that this can be done by calling the stored procedure through EF and binding the results to the relevant class objects and passing them to the `view` but I really want to know if this can be done without calling the stored procedure i.e., through LINQ statements without multiple calls to database.

Comment: please edit your linq statements: all tdata are the same in your case and contain context.Table1

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot return multiple resultsets with EF unless you run a stored proc with EF. Thus, it seems that you should either continue using the same SP, or you should write multiple queries with EF.

Comment: I have edited the question